# How to attach the sound file to my app without need to put the sound file in my app directory .?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'am trying to make my app plays sound using this code by putting the sound file in my app directory .

Dim s As String 
s= Application.StartupPath & "\Infected.wav"
My.Computer.Audio.Play(s)

But Is there a method to attach the sound file to my app without need to put the sound file in my app directory .

Comment: Yes. [Embedded resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e2c9s1d7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but what the code to make embedded sound file plays on my app ? I followed the instruction in embedded resources page but now how to program a button to run my sound file to play ? Thanks advance

Comment: Thanks I got it by using this piece of code My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Ding, AudioPlayMode.Background)

Answer (score 0):

Put your sounds into the source of your application.
After that you just need to put my.resources.your file into your audio playing code.
Refer to this link :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233807.aspx